# send message to whole windows network?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I've just discovered that you can use this command to send a message to one pc on the network

> msg *username* /SERVER:*hostname* /V message to send

is there some command (something like below that i've just made up) that will send it to all pcs on the network?

> msg /SERVER:192.168.1.* /V message to send

Comment: Are you talking about the "net send" command?

Comment: formerly known as net send. To my understanding, "msg" is the post-xp replacement for net send

Comment: Ah, I think I just found something on that. I'll post it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Message all users** that are logged in the Network right now:

```
msg * Hi, Happy Monday!
```

---

**Message all users on a list**.

Type the command to read the list:

```
msg @users.txt Hi this is a message to team members on the list.
```

---

Get list of Network Users. Type the command:

```
net users
```

To put this users into a text file. Type the command:

```
net users > users.txt
```

Modify the list so that each user is on it's own line. Like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

For a complete list of commands:
[Link to a comprehensive complete list](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/)

Comment: am I phrasing something wrong? cause this seems what everybody says. The issue is I want to send this message to an entirely seperate PC. Example: I have 3 laptops in the room, and I want to send a message from one lapotp to both others without having to individually specify them.

Comment: ...then again, it appears maybe i was wrong with the command usage as I can't seem to get the message to send to a different PC anyway

Comment: or this is due to my lack of understanding of domain vs workgroup vs network

Comment: Is everyone on the same network? I believe that every computer has to have the same Workgroup name. All the computers in my house are all in the same workgroup.

Comment: not sure how i check the work group... They are all connected to the same wifi router

Comment: You can right-click on MyComputer, properties. Check Workgroup. Change Settings and make sure you have the same name for Workgroup on each computer.

Comment: ok, provided this has been accomplished, will the first command actually send the message to another physically different machine?

Comment: You might have to use the IP address of each computer. The IP address on your router should look something like 192.168.1.1. Each physical computer will have a unique IP address. You can verify each PC's IP address is using the command "ipconfig", using command-line interface. If you don't have static IP enforced, and/or static IP's assigned to each PC, then they could change. However, what you asked for has been answered. The rest will be a learning activity.

Comment: What I have asked has not been answered. I knew how to do most of this already. I want to know if there is a way to send a message to every physical computer on a network simultaneously without having to individually specify them.

Comment: You need to edit your original question to reflect the nature of your home network. "How to set up a server so that I can message all my PC's". Right now, as it states, you are looking for a "command". The command is there. The command isn't your problem as you stated it. You want to know how to set up a home network correctly and/or set up a server station. I suggest you close this and rethink your real problem, which is your network and lack of a server for said home network.

Comment: alright, seems like what I want isn't possible in this manner. Thank you for your help